# Ordering WP_User_Query results by the user IDs used in the include parameter

Tags: wp-user-query

I'm using `WP_User_Query` to bring back a list of users. I'm passing a list of specific users to be included in results. For example:

```
    $user_ids = array( 1, 5, 9, 61, 24, 12 );

    $args = array(
        'include' => $user_ids,
        'count_total' => true,
        'search' => sanitize_text_field( $_GET['phrase'] )
    );

    $query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

Results are currently ordered by `user_login`. How can I modify my query so that the results returned are ordered by my `$user_id` array? For example, if 3 users are to be returned (let's say IDs 5, 61 and 12), then user 5 should be displayed first, user 61 second and user 12 third.

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that instead of dealing with complex SQL queries and ways to make WordPress use them, a simple [`uasort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) can do the trick:

```
$uids = array( 1 );

$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'include' => $uids ) );

$users = (array) $user_query->results;

usort( $users, function( $a, $b ) use( $uids ) {
  return array_search( $a->ID, $uids) < array_search( $b->ID, $uids ) ? -1 : 1;
} );

// use as usual
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    echo '<p>' . $user->display_name . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: out of interest, is there a way to achieve the same effect by modifying the actual query (instead of using `usort` after the query has run)?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's late, but if someone interested try:
$args['orderby'] = 'include';

Worked for me..

Comment: Hi Dima, thanks for your answer. Would you mind editing it to explain further why this works/what it does? Thanks very much!