# How to order WP_User_Query results to match the order of an array of user IDs?

Tags: php, query, wp-user-query

I'm using `WP_User_Query` to get a list of users from my database. I'm showing specific users only via use of the `include` parameter. For example:

```
$args = array(
    'include' => array( 1, 3, 5, 99, 61, 24, 12 ),
    'count_total' => true,
    'search' => sanitize_text_field( $_GET['phrase'] )
);

$query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
foreach( $query->results as $user ) {
    echo $user->ID . '<br />';
}
```

Results are currently ordered by `user_login`. My aim is to order results by the user IDs used in the `include` parameter. So for example, if 5 users are to be returned (let's say user IDs 1, 5, 99, 61 and 12), then I need the foreach loop to output results in this order:

```
1
5
99
61
12
```

**Please note** I've tried using `usort()` after the query has run (see [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166907/ordering-wp-user-query-results-by-the-user-ids-used-in-the-include-parameter)), but now I need the actual query results to be ordered. I don't wish to order the query results after the query has run.

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Updated:*

The `WP_User_Query` class, in WordPress 4.1+, supports it with :

```
'orderby' => 'include'
```

Since WordPress 4.7 there's also support for:

```
'orderby' => 'login__in'
```

and

```
'orderby' => 'nicename__in'
```

So we no longer need to implement it through a filter, like we did here below.

### Previous Answer:

I wonder if this works for you:

```
add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'wpse_order_by_include_values' )
$query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
remove_action( 'pre_user_query', 'wpse_order_by_include_values' )
```

where

```
function wpse_order_by_include_values( $q )
{
    if( isset( $q->query_vars['include'] ) )
    {
        $values = join( ',', $q->query_vars['include'] );
        $q->query_orderby = 'ORDER BY FIELD( ID,' . $values . ' )';         
    }
}
```

using the [`FIELD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function in MySQL. There are some usage examples [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html) in the comments of the MySQL doc page.

**Update:**

To make it more flexible we could use this mini plugin:

```
/**
 * Support the 'orderby' => '_include' parameter for the WP_User_Query 
 * to order by the values in the include array.
 * 
 * @see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/167095/26350
 */

add_action( 'pre_user_query', function( $q ) {

    if( 
        isset( $q->query_vars['orderby'] )
        && '_include' === $q->query_vars['orderby']
        && isset( $q->query_vars['include'] ) 
        && count( $q->query_vars['include'] ) > 0 
    )
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $users_in = join( ',', array_map( 'absint', $q->query_vars['include'] ) );
        $q->query_orderby = 'ORDER BY FIELD( {$wpdb->users}.ID,' . $users_in . ' )';
    }

});
```

where we use the underscore prefix `_include`, just in case the core will use the `include` value in the future. *Update*: I've adjusted this so now it's more or less similar to the `post__in` ordering case of the `WP_Query` class.

Now you can simply use:

```
$args = array(
    'include'     => array( 1, 3, 5, 99, 61, 24, 12 ),
    'count_total' => true,
    'search'      => sanitize_text_field( $_GET['phrase'] )
    'orderby'     => '_include',                               //<-- our new value
);

$query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

to order by the `include` array.

Comment: Thanks @birgire, the approach looks great (I never thought to filter pre_user_query) but it doesn't produce the results I expect. `$values = join( ',', $q->query_vars['include'] )` produces a comma-sep list of IDs which is good. So, I'm assuming the problem is with `'ORDER BY FIELD( ID,' . $values . ' )'`

Comment: ok great, I'm going off-line so I will check this better when I get back.

Comment: OK no problem! any help is appreciated :)

Comment: It seems to work as expected on my install. How does your SQL query look like?

Comment: my apologies, it does in fact produce the results I expect. I forgot to use this solution **with** the [solution](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166978/how-to-sort-results-from-a-custom-database-table) you helped me out with yesterday

Comment: ok great you got it resolved, I updated the answer with a more flexible method by introducing the `'orderby' => 'include'` option in the `WP_User_Query`.

Comment: Wow! you've gone above and beyond with the plugin, it's a super clean solution to a problem I honestly nearly gave up on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18322/discussion-between-henrywright-and-birgire).

Comment: What happens if you unset $query_orderby at pre_user_query? Would that disable sorting altogether and return in the order that they are queried? array( 1, 3, 5, 99, 61, 24, 12 )

Comment: @RyanLoremIpsum Good suggestion but it looks like the order then becomes unpredictable and it's recommended to always specify the order. Check for example these threads [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746519/sql-what-is-the-default-order-by-of-queries), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949641/mysql-row-order-for-select-from-table-name) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793147/sql-best-practice-to-deal-with-default-sort-order)

Comment: Fascinating! Apparently, as far as the actual SQL query is concerned, `ORDER BY` must be used to return data in the [order of insertion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656476/mysql-order-by-insertion-order-no-sorting-columns).

Comment: Good thinking adding the underscore prefix to `include` in case core uses the `include` value in future. Take `WP_Query` for example, you can already do `'orderby' => 'post__in'` so something similar for `WP_User_Query` may well make it into core at some point. In the mean time, your solution has it covered! :)

Comment: You're correct about the `post__in` ordering, I checked and it's also using the `FIELD` function to order by values. I've updated the answer so it's now handled in a similar way as in the `WP_Query` class.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative offered to the above answer is to add a column (meta key) with meta values which can easily be sorted with `'orderby' => 'meta_value'` in the args.

Here is a function I wrote to add the meta values to each user. I'm including it here because `$my_order_ids = array( 3, 4, 6, 2, 5 );` determines the ascending order users should be sorted by in your query.

```
function my_order_column() {
// Defines the user IDs to be updated.
// Use the desired order when you define this.
$my_order_ids = array( 3, 4, 6, 2, 5 );

    // Runs only when $my_order_ids has changed by comparing  
    // it to _transient_my_order_column. 
    if (false === get_transient('my_order_column') ||
        get_transient('my_order_column') !== $my_order_ids) {

        // Updates _transient_my_order_column
        set_transient('my_order_column', $my_order_ids);

        // The first user
        $order_id = 1;
        // Add an integer value for each user 
        foreach ($my_order_ids as $user_id) {

        // Sets/updates the value of my_user_order
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'my_user_order', $order_id );

        // Confirms that the new value of my_user_order matches the 
        // current value of $order_id
        if ( get_user_meta($user_id,  'my_user_order', true ) != $order_id )
            wp_die('An error occurred');

            $order_id++;
        }
    ?><div class="updated">
        <p><?php echo var_dump($my_order_ids) . '<br />Updated!'; ?></p>
    </div><?php
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_order_column' );
```

This uses a foreach loop to add a new integer value to each user's `my_user_order` key, incrementing by 1 each time. All you need to do is define `$my_order_ids` in the order you want them to be sorted later.

The transient is just there so that the updates will only run when the values of `$my_order_ids` has changed (in other words, only update users once). You may want to comment out `add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_order_column' );` to prevent it from running unexpectedly if the transient is lost.

Now that our new custom meta key and meta values are set, we should have no problem getting the query to order them this way.

```
function my_user_query() {

$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',     /***************************************/
    'order' => 'ASC',              /***Added orderby, order and meta_key***/
    'meta_key' => 'my_user_order', /***************************************/
    // Note: 'include' does not affect how output will be ordered. 
    // array( 6, 5, 3, 2, 4 ) would still be ordered by meta_value.
    'include' => array( 3, 4, 6, 2, 5 ),
    'count_total' => true,
    'search' => sanitize_text_field( $_GET['phrase'] )
);

$query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

    ?>
    <div class="updated">
        <p><?php foreach( $query->results as $user ) {
        echo $user->ID . '<br />'; } ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php  wp_reset_query();
}

add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_user_query' );
```

In the above example, the following output is displayed as an admin notice:

```
3
4
6
2
5
```