# get only one last comment from each post

Tags: comments

Lets say I have 5 posts where most recent comments placed. How can I get one comment per each of these posts? I want to use get_comments(). Is it possible?

```
Post1: Comment 1
       Comment 6
Post2: Comment 2
Post3: Comment 5
       Comment 7
Post4: Comment 3
       Comment 4
Post5: Comment 8
```

The result should look like this:

```
Comment8
Comment7
Comment6
Comment4
Comment2
```

Comment: So 5 calls to `get_comments` followed by some logic to merge them all together. Can I ask why you're trying to do this?

Comment: @TomJNowell Because I want to show 5 last commented posts with one last comment rather than 5 comments from one post. I think it would be more informative for my users

Comment: @PieterGoosen Please could you send an example of parameters?

Comment: @TomJNowell The question is: which logic I have to use?

Comment: How do you select these 5 posts? The most recent ones?

Comment: The logic needed is just basic pure PHP array skills, every time you grab a comment you put it in an array. At the end you display the things in the array

Comment: @birgire Last comment from each recent commented post.

Comment: @TomJNowell Do you think it might be better to make this logic using one simple MySQL query instead of get_comments() ? I think if it is impossible to make this selection by native way, pure PHP recipe should be better.

Comment: You misunderstand, it ***is*** possible, but it involves multiple calls. Doing it via SQL would be similar to buying a steamroller because you want to flatten 2 pieces of paper but can't do it at the same time with a single book. It takes more effort, more of your time, and the end result is an array of the comments you need to display ( which is what we were telling you to do in the first place, e.g. `$my_array[] = 'hello Im a comment';` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Constructing the SQL query:

You can try the following:

```
/**
 * Fetch comments' IDs for the most recently commented posts 
 * (only one comment per post)
 *
 * @param  integer $count
 * @return array  
 */

function get_cids_wpse ( $count = 5 )
{
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "SELECT MAX( comment_ID ) as cid 
            FROM {$wpdb->comments} 
            GROUP BY comment_post_ID
            ORDER BY cid DESC
            LIMIT 0, %d"; 
    return $wpdb->get_cols( $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $count ) );
}
```

where I assume that the comments' date have the same order as the IDs. If that's not the case for your setup, then we need to adjust this further.

### Usage examples:

If we need to get the last 5 comments per post, we can use:

```
$cids = get_cids_wpse( 5 );
$comments = array();
foreach( (array) $cids as $cid )
{
    $comments[] = get_comment( $cid );
}
```

or this setup:

```
$args = array(
    'include'     => get_cids_wpse( 5 );,
    'orderby'     => '_include',           //<-- custom parameter
);

$comments = get_comments( $args );
```

where we use [this code snippet](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/167095/26350) to order by the include values.

*Notice:* You could also expand this example further, with more comments db fields and then use the `get_results()` method instead of `get_col()`. Then you would only use a single db query to fetch all the comments data.

Comment: Thanks, it works as expected. Could I use array of IDs to get all comments in one get_comments() call instead of cycling over them?

Comment: ok great, I updated the answer.